# Redirected output is interpreted when file is given as a variable

Tags: bash, unix, text, echo

When I do the following within a bash script file:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo -E $line >> 2.txt
```

... the $line is written inside 2.txt file without any troubles. However, if I use a variable for the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file='2.txt'
echo -E $line >> $file
```

... the escaped \$ is interpreted and in the file only a '$' character is written. Outside of the bash script file (in a Bash console) both codes work. Does anybody know why? I could not get information on that on the Internet.

Comment: There is no such difference; you must be misunderstanding what is going on. What is the content of the `line` variable? (What does `printf '<%s>\n' "$line"` print?)

Comment: Yes, you are right... I must had been missing something in my previous code version... sorry and thanks for the help.